Azure b2c cutom policy signin validation profile
Hi i would like to create a custom policy tosign up/sign in Azure b2c with a validation profile, if user email does not exist in local Db it should fail, if user email exist in the local db but is the first time, it must register this user in Azure B2C with this idp and store this idp in local db and continue with the usr journey as authenticated user, if the user email and idp match the one store in the local db, it should conntinue with the signin user journey.
I created a signup/signin custom policy disabling the sign up, now I am creating a validation profile to check for the user in the local db that will check for the email and idp, but I am not sure if I cuould use this same user journey to sign up this user if its the first time signin in with Azure b2c and the email exist in the local db. Is this possible?
